# Creating infix function

Tags: haskell

I can define a function like this

```
method1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
method1 a b = a + b

main = print $ 1 `method1` 2
```

What if I don't want to use `` each time I call the function, but yet I want to use it in the infix form, how do I do that?

```
method1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
method1 a b = a + b

main = print $ 1 method1 2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the short answer is, you can't. Imagine the horrible ambiguity with `a b c` if `b` is potentially infix. But you can define an operator to do this for you. Any of these will work

```
a |+| b   = method1
(|+|) a b = method1 a b 
(|+|)     = method1
```

Then

```
a |+| b === a `method1` b === method1 a b
```

The permissible characeters for haskell's infix operators is limited, choose from

```
:|!@#$%^&*-+./<>?\~
```

A common library, lens, has lots of operators that act as synonyms for longer names. It's quite common. Please do use judgement though, otherwise you'll end up with more perl than Haskell :)

Comment: Note:  an operator begining with a `:` (colon) is actually an infix type constructor.  That is a colon is the operator equivalent of a capital letter. I personally find this a highly annoying feature, but I like the Data.Sequence library so I have learned to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a vile and nasty "solution" to this - using a CPP macro. Eg:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

#define method1 `themethod`
module Main where

themethod x y = x + y

someValue = 3 method1 4
```

This compiles, and in ghci, `someValue` will equal 7. Please don't do this however...

Comment: This is brilliant in a twisted way :) Though you'd need to defined a synonym so you can `map`  with it and stuff